# iTerm2 & Atom - Switch profiles based on input bash commands in ~/.bash_profile, looking for suggestions

Tags: bash, terminal, atom-editor, iterm2, iterm

The weather has gotten pretty decent where I am at and recently I've been working outside more often than not. Usually when inside I use a dark theme that is comfortable for the eye, but outside, obviously, I can't see crap and resort to changing iTerm & Atom themes' to ones with a light background.

I'm a man of shortcuts, and after doing some investigation online and some Googling **I haven't seen anything that would allow me to change iTerm's or Atom's configuration directly via the terminal.** **The objective would be to type `light` to change my Atom's and iTerm's configuration to a lighter theme, and `dark` to change them back to dark (via `~/.bash_profile`).**

Regarding iTerm in specific, my idea was to directly modify the configuration file at `~/Library/Prferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist` when the commands are run. More specifically (so I don't have to deal with converting `.plist` files to `.xml` and then back) I would just set up two git branches and flip between them on command.

However, the solution above is extremely bootleg, and not effectively transferable over to other machines, which I do like to be the cases I reformat my computer (yearly clean). I was wondering if someone would have an idea, or has encountered something similar to this and would be willing to give some suggestions that might possibly work.

Much appreciated!

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/s-2_nw/change-iterm2-color-profile-from-the-cli for iterm2 for atom there's multiple configs you can use I think your preference will dictate which one you use though e.g. https://atom.io/packages/theme-switch / https://atom.io/packages/dark-mode / https://atom.io/packages/mojave-dark-mode etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on 10.14 or later (with system dark theme) you can have both of those applications sync with the system dark theme...

To make iTerm sync with system dark, [follow these instructions](https://apas.gr/2018/11/dark-mode-macos-safari-iterm-vim/). Basically make a Dark and Light profile in iTerm, and drop this in a bash profile. More details at that link if needed.

```
if [[ "$(uname -s)" == "Darwin" ]]; then
    sith() {
        val=$(defaults read -g AppleInterfaceStyle 2>/dev/null)
        if [[ $val == "Dark" ]]; then
            i
        fi
    }

    i() {
        if [[ $ITERM_PROFILE == "Terminal" ]]; then
            echo -ne "\033]50;SetProfile=Dark\a"
            export ITERM_PROFILE="Dark"
        else
            echo -ne "\033]50;SetProfile=Terminal\a"
            export ITERM_PROFILE="Terminal"
        fi
    }

    sith
fi
```

To make Atom sync with the system dark theme, use [dark-mode](https://atom.io/packages/dark-mode) or [mojave-dark-mode](https://atom.io/packages/mojave-dark-mode).

Finally, you can easily toggle between light and dark mode either from Alfred with [this plugin](https://github.com/sindresorhus/alfred-dark-mode), an app called [Shifty](https://shifty.natethompson.io/en/), or via `/usr/bin/osascript` with this command... (you can call it from a bash script and wire it up however you need).

```
systemEvents.appearancePreferences.darkMode = !systemEvents.appearancePreferences.darkMode()
```

Comment: Oh man, I'm going to give this a try! I appreciate the post. If everything works as expected I'll go ahead and reward +50. Thank you!